# How to use inner join in hql using subqueries

Tags: hql

I am new to HQL.
I have a table like
[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqjeN.jpg)
I have a query like

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "Select f from Product f where f.Type=1 and f.EmpId='" + empId + "' and f.Status IN ("+allowedStatus+")");

empId=Abc and allowedStatus = (1,2)
```

After hitting this query I am getting all rows whose status is 2.

My problem is I want to find only those rows whose version is largest(for all ProductId) along with status is 2.

My O/P should look like:
[Final Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63M1p.jpg)

I have written a query in SQL like:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM Product f
INNER JOIN
 (Select ProductID, Max(ProductVersion) AS Version , EmpId from Product f 
 WHERE f.Type=1 and f.empId='abc' and f.Status IN (1,2) 
 GROUP BY ProductID, empID) AS groupedtt 
ON f.ProductID = groupedtt.Product
AND f.ProductVersion = groupedtt.ProductVersion
```

But it is showing me error below:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 72 [Select f from Product f inner join (Select f.ProductId, max(f.Version) As version from Product f where f.Type=1 and f.empid='abc' and f.Status IN (1,2) group by ProductId) AS groupeIt on f.ProductId = groupeIt.ProductId and f.Version = groupeIt.Version]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)`

Comment: HQL just can do sub-query in SELECT or WHERE clause. So you need rewrite your HQL to have same result. Check this [https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-subqueries.htm](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to perform some kind of sub queries with HQL. One of them is the `SELECT` after a `JOIN`, as you are trying to do here:

```
INNER JOIN
    (Select ProductID, Max(ProductVersion) AS Version , EmpId from Product f
```